# Drupal Custom Theme Missing CSS

Tags: php, html, css, drupal, drupal-7

I am getting a Drupal site to work on my localhost. Currently, it seems to output some content (database is working) but nothing is styled.

When I look in the source-code, I see this:

```
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:88/sites/MAA/" media="all" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:88/sites/MAA/" media="all" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:88/sites/MAA/" media="all" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:88/sites/MAA/" media="screen" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:88/sites/MAA/" media="all" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:88/sites/MAA/" media="all" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:88/sites/MAA/" media="all" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:88/sites/MAA/" media="print" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:88/sites/MAA/" media="all" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:88/sites/MAA/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js?v=1.8.3"></script>
```

That is, the template's CSS are not being included, except for the path part to the site. Now, the .info file is as follows:

```
; Stylesheets. Anything within the "framework" folder will be placed before all others.
stylesheets[all][] = styles/framework/reset.css
stylesheets[all][] = styles/framework/text.css
stylesheets[all][] = styles/framework/960.css
stylesheets[all][] = styles/framework/debug.css
stylesheets[all][] = styles/css/css_hides.css

; Theme specific styles. Any sub-themes should override this.
stylesheets[all][] = styles/skin.css
stylesheets[all][] = styles/maa.css
stylesheets[all][] = styles/maa-legacy.css
stylesheets[all][] = styles/jq-ui-date-range-picker/ui.daterangepicker.css
stylesheets[all][] = styles/styles_nvl.css
stylesheets[all][] = styles/css_hides.css
stylesheets[print][] = styles/print.css

; Theme specific scripts.
scripts[] = "js/enlargeit.js"
scripts[] = "js/jquery-ui.js"
scripts[] = "js/custom.js"

regions[page_top]              = Page top
regions[header]                = Header
regions[search_box]            = Search Box
regions[main_nav]              = Main Navigation
regions[highlighted]           = Highlight
regions[featured]              = Featured
regions[help]                  = Help
regions[home_content]          = Home Content
regions[home_content_bottom]   = Home Content Bottom
regions[content]               = Content
regions[sidebar_first]         = Left sidebar
regions[sidebar_second]        = Right sidebar
regions[footer_top]            = Footer Top
regions[footer_top_left]       = Footer Top Left
regions[footer_top_center_one] = Footer Top Center 1
regions[footer_top_center_two] = Footer Top Center 2
regions[footer_top_right]      = Footer Top Right
regions[footer_left]           = Footer Left
regions[footer_right]          = Footer Right
regions[page_bottom]           = Page bottom
```

Could anyone tell where I should look to troubleshoot this? Inside the html.tpl.php file, there is a line that outputs styles, but I cannot find where it is populated.

```
 <?php print $styles; ?>
 <?php print $scripts; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step number one in solving any Drupal problem: 
Have you tried clearing the cache?
(It's the Drupal equivalent of "Have you tried turning it off and back on again?")

How to clear the cache: 
If you are logged into the site as an administrator, go to Configuration > Development > Performance. You should see a "Clear All Caches" button.

If that doesn't work:
Have you checked out the Drupal docs?
https://www.drupal.org/node/171209

What happens if you aggregate and compress CSS files (a setting in Configuration > Development > Performance)?

Comment: I can't seem to do any of these since I cant login. All I get is a front page with its content and unstylized menu. When I click on entries in the menu, proper pages load, but remain unstylized.

Comment: Do you have login credentials? Drush can assist with recovering credentials - Learn about Drush here: https://www.drupal.org/drush-faq Here's a link to download it: http://docs.drush.org/en/master/  It's a command-line tool that can do drupal administration tasks. There are things that you will need to do either as an admin within the interface or from the command line - one is clearing caches. Drupal as a system does a lot of caching for performance reasons. You won't see your changes unless you convince it to let go of that cached info.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. I shall start learning it. Also, I do have login credentials. That is, I dumped this database from a live site on which I had valid credentials. Is there some kind of idiosyncrasy in how Drupal may treat such migration?

Comment: The credentials you use to log in at mysite.com/user (or mysite.com/?q=user if you don't have clean URLs enabled) are different from the credentials that the site uses to communicate with the database. Drush can help you recover the "user-1" administrator login data. http://drushcommands.com/drush-7x/user/user-login/

Comment: I have been playing around with Drush in last couple of days. It seems like a great tool! Thank you. At this point, I decided to abandon Windows attempts and moved the entire site to a Linux server. Now, my front page loads with styles and links, albeit some images are missing. However, when I click on any menu, I get Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: I checked and changed the base_url to "http://IP/sitedirectory" but this does not seem to do it. If I change it to "http://default" styles disappear but some content still loads. Is there another setting I should look at? Would Drush be able to fix something like this?

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this issue when cloning a site from production onto my local machine.  Production and staging environments were fine, so I started troubleshooting my machine.

The prior answers are definitely good places to start when encountering this specific issue.  However, the real culprit seems to be how Drupal uses the filesystem when registering the style sheets.

Generally speaking, your `html.tpl.php` file will have a `$styles` variable.  This is a string that is output and contains all the style sheets you register in your theme's `.info` file.  You may or may not have a preprocess hook altering your css files in your `template.php` file.

After tracing all of this back and confirming that it was correct, running a system status report will help you identify areas that you need to address.  In this specific scenario it was a Drupal 7 site using the `ctools` module.  Browsing to `/admin/reports/status` after logging in revealed that ctools could not create the right directory in `/sites/default/files/ctools/`.

The result was that Drupal would remove the URI's from my style sheets if it could not create this directory.  The data driving the output for each stylesheet is coming from your `.info` and any preprocess functions that add css.

I hope this helps anyone else that has encountered this problem and is left scratching their head.